# How to write JUnit for a method that throws IOException and also takes in ResourceRequest as an argument

Tags: java, junit

Following is the code for a method that takes ResourceRequest as the argument

```
JSONObject updateDetail(ResourceRequest request) throws IOException {
    
    BufferedReader resourceReqBr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(request.getPortletInputStream()));
    String resourceReqStr = resourceReqBr.readLine();
    JSONObject updateCaDetailJsn = JSONObject.parse(resourceReqStr);
    
}
```

Here request.getPortletInputStream(), resourceReqBr.readLine(), and JSONObject.parse(resourceReqStr) are the lines of code that throw IOException. How do i setup request object such that it throws IOException.

My test code:

```
@Mock
    private ResourceRequest request;

@Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
    public void testUpdatDetailIOException() throws Exception
    {
        expectedException.expect(IOException.class);
        foo.updateDetail(request);
    }
```

This is causing nullpointer error (which is obvious).

Comment: you can mock your method call, so that as soon that  it's called, it throws the Exception you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking a method call of ResourceRequest just to throw a IOException is in my opinion a not the only test case.

I would also try to make the JSONParser throw the IOException. For example expect an IOException when json string is faulty.

```
@Test
public void if_IOException_is_thrown_when_json_is_faulty() throws Exception {

  expectedException.expect(IOException.class);
  ResourceRequest mockResourceRequest = Mockito.mock(ResourceRequest.class);
  Mockito.when(mockResourceRequest.getPortletInputStream()).thenReturn(
      new ByteArrayInputStream("{[broken".getBytes(UTF_8)));
  foo.updateDetail(mockResourceRequest);
}
```

Comment: What will be the value for UTF_8 ?

Comment: Sorry my IDE replaced it with a static import:
``java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8``

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to write two test methods, one as in above first answer and then this one?

Comment: Yes, you could write two methods if you like to test both cases. I personally don't think the other test makes so much sense. But if you for example want to ensure that the IOException of the method ``getPortletInputStream()`` is not swallowed by ``updateDetail(..)`` then both methods make sense.

Comment: how about setting up request to test JSONObject.parse(request.getParameter("deleteData")); to throw io exception. Here deleteData gives json data.

Comment: Yes, of course. That is also possible. It always depends on your method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try below mocking in ur test code

```
ResourceRequest mockResourceRequest = Mockito.mock(ResourceRequest.class);
Mockito.when(mockResourceRequest.getPortletInputStream()).thenThrow(new IOException);
foo.updateDetail(mockResourceRequest);
```